# fscanf Issue-Not able to extract string from file

Tags: c, scanf, file-handling, fgets

the program is working when i am using getc but it is not working with this code.
I tried printing random text inside while loop it got printed with NULL.

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *str=NULL;
    char s;

    fp=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCAN NOT OPEN FILE");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)!=EOF) 
{
      printf("%s",str); //not taking any values in str,prints NULL 
  }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Use `str[100]` with `fscanf`.

Comment: What is example text in the file `fscanf(fp,"%s",str)` is to read?

Comment: @Observer whats the problem with character pointers?

Comment: @chux just random words.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
char *str=NULL;
```

`str` is a pointer variable & it's initialized with `NULL` that's very fine but to store something into `str` i.e to read the word from file, and store into `str` it should have valid memory. So either allocate memory dynamically for `str`

```
str = malloc(SIZE); /* define SIZE */
```

Or use array of characters like

```
char str[100]; /* let say each word of file is less than 100 char's */
```

For e.g

```
char str[100];
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)!=EOF) {
      printf("%s",str); 
}
```

Also instead of `void main() { }` use

```
int main(void) {
    /* some_code */
    return 0;    
}
```

as you can see from  [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.1.2.2.1 **Program startup**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this statement:

```
char *str=NULL;
```

Since you are using `fscanf` to read words which are character arrays, you have to read them into a valid memory location. So `str` should be a `char` array whose length should be equal to the longest word in your file plus 1 (for null termination).

So change the above to:

```
char str[256];
```

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>   ...
>
> 12 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> s -  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.
>   If no l length modifier is present, **the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character**, which will be added automatically.